# Convergence of double integral with variable

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, indefinite-integrals

For which values of $p>0$ does the the double integral
$$ \int \int_D  \frac{1}{(x^4+2x^3y+3x^2y^2+3xy^3+y^2)^p} $$
where

$$D= {xy:x^2+y^2<1}$$

converge? $\textit{Tip: Try to use symmetries in the integrand to find substitutions to simpify the expression.}$

I have tried the following to simplify the denominator, but that doesn't seem to make the problem easier.

What could be a useful "symmetry in the integrand"?

$$x^4+2x^3y+3x^2y^2+2xy^3+y^4= \frac{(x+y)^4+x^4+y^4}{2}= \frac{((x+y)^2)^2+x^4+y^4}{2}= \frac{(x^2+y^2+2xy)^2+x^4+y^4}{2}$$

$\begin{cases}
 x = rcos(t)\\    
 y = rsin(t)    
\end{cases}$
gives

$$= \frac{(r^2+r^22cost(t)sin(t))^2+r^4cos^4(t)+r^4sin^4(t)}{2}=\frac{(r^2+r^2sin(2t))^2+r^4((cos^2(t)+sin^2(t))^2-2sin^2(t)cos^2(t))}{2}$$

$$=\frac{r^4(1+2sin(2t)+sin^2(2t)+1-\frac{1}{2}sin^2(2t))}{2}=\frac{r^4(2+2sin(2t)+\frac{1}{2}sin^2(2t)}{2}=r^4(1+sin(2t)+\frac{1}{4}sin^2(2t))$$

So this would result in

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{r^3} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(1+sin(2t)+\frac{1}{4}sin^2(2t))^p}drdt$$
but here I'm stuck..

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, we can move to polar coordinates, yielding something of the form
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \dfrac{g(\theta)}{r^3} dr d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} g(\theta)\int_0^1\frac{1}{r^3} dr \, d\theta
$$

Depending on how you are defining the convergence of improper double integrals, this may show that it does not converge (because one of the iterated integrals, for a particular order of integration, does not converge).

Comment: Yes, thanks. But the problem is I don't see how to get a manageable $g(\theta)$.